# rails db:migrate aborted NoMethodError: undefined method 'type' in 'interview' factory Did you mean? 'type { :regular }'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After updating my gems, Rails version was updated to latest (6.0.2.2). There on I'm getting below error for Rake, looks like it is related to factories generated by FactoryBot. Do we need to regenerate the factories based on gem updates? If so how do we regenerate.

Error:

```
web_1  | rake aborted!
web_1  | NoMethodError: undefined method 'type' in 'interview' factory
web_1  | Did you mean? 'type { :regular }'
```

Comment: What's the rake command you're running? How does the factory file pointed look like?

Comment: I'm trying to setup my environment using docker-compose.yml, in my startup.sh I'm using  bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate db:seed.
Here is the partial file of factory. I tried to update based on the suggestion, but it is giving same error for other factory file.
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :interview do
    type :regular
    proxy :no
    completed false
    current_question_index 1

    factory :initial_interview do
      type :initial
    end

Comment: Does the type column exists in the database table to what that factory belongs to?

Comment: No it is not able to create the the database tables, as the rake db:create is failing

Comment: I'm not really sure if `type` is a reserved word in Ruby and/or Rails, try temporarily removing that from the factory.

Comment: After reverting all the latest changes in Gemfile.lock back to original, everything works fine. Looks like it is something related to latest version